# Access passport strategy from passport

Tags: javascript, passport.js

I use passport with *passport-saml Strategy*. On the *Strategy*, there is a function I would want to use. I know that the *strategy* is taken into use like this:

```
const SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;

   passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
   {//options here...}, ...);
```

Now how could I access the *strategy* (and its function) from the `passport` variable afterwards? Something like `passport.Strategy.functionIWantToCall()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve a strategy object by name using `passport._strategy(NAME)`, and the function by `_verify` on that object:

```
var strategy = passport._strategy('saml');
var func     = strategy._verify;
```

However, notice that all of these accessors are prefixed with an underscore, meaning that they should be considered *private* (they aren't documented, I found them in the source code). They aren't meant to be accessed like this, only by Passport internally.

A better solution would be to create a separate module to encapsulate the strategy object:

```
// my-strategy.js
module.exports = new SamlStrategy(...);

// In your Passport setup:
...
passport.use(require('./my-strategy')));
...

// And elsewhere where you need to access the strategy:
var strategy = require('./my-strategy');
```

Comment: But I want to use function named logout from the strategy, not verify. Looking the source of passport-saml, I see that the strategy has a prototype function: Strategy.prototype.logout = function(req, callback) {
  this._saml.getLogoutUrl(req, callback);
};

Comment: yes, but that doesn't seem to do anything. It doesn't fire the logout saml requests etc, networking shows empty =/. It doesn't call the Strategy.prototype.logout(). I saw someone did the logout like this: https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml/pull/93, so I thought it could work like that

Comment: Hmm you're right, it doesn't call any strategy logout handlers. I'll take a further look at it.

Comment: @VilleMiekk-oja `req.logout()` is probably not the right way. I edited my answer to show how you can store a reference to the strategy, so you can use `strategy.logout()` as mentioned in the GitHub PR.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: There's no need to wrap the strategy in a module if you need to access it in one module only. What I had when I made the pull request was simply `var samlStrategy = new SamlStrategy(...); passport.use(samlStrategy);`

Comment: @vesse sure, if all the code that requires access to the strategy is in one file, you don't have to modularize it. But usually, with moderately complex Express apps, you have the Express setup in one file, routing in a bunch of others, etc.

Answer (score 0):

solved with this

```
export class AuthController {
    constructor(private readonly samlStrategy: SamlStrategy) {
    }
    public logout(@Req() req, @Res() res) {     
       // Work around
       (this.samlStrategy as any).logout(req, function (err, req) {
            if (!err) {
                res.send('<h1>Logout Failure!!</h1>');
            }
        });
    }
}
```